# How can I add custom mode in Alexa smart home skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am implementing smart home skill in which user will change mode. I found Alexa supported few inbuild modes and for user-defined mode they have CUSTOM mode mechanism. Over the documentation they mention below JSON need to set:

```
{
  "name": "thermostatMode",
  "value": {
    "value": "CUSTOM",
    "customName": "VENDOR_HEAT_COOL"
  }
}
```

Question: Where do we need to set above JSON.
I tried to add above JSON under **Alexa.ThermostatController** interface of device discovery response, but it is not working.

Comment: Not used yet, but what about mode controller ? (https://developer.amazon.com/it-IT/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-modecontroller.html)

Comment: The custom `thermostatMode` isn't something that can be used - I think this was something that was planned but never made generally available for use. I think it is because utterances with the name would need to be manually added/maintained.

As @fcracker79 has mentioned, you should use the ModeController for this.

However, is your heat/cool mode not what Amazon refer to as `AUTO`? https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-property-schemas.html#thermostat-mode-values

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use Thermostat Controller which only supports below modes but if you have custom modes then better to use primitive controller like "ModeController" where you can provide custom modes details in discovery response.

AUTO    Indicates automatic heating or cooling based on the current temperature and the setpoint.

COOL    Indicates cooling mode.

HEAT    Indicates heating mode.

ECO         Indicates economy mode.

OFF         Indicates that heating and cooling is off, but the device might still have power.

More info about ModeController:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-modecontroller.html